# Get sum of a field per page in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, paging, subtotal

I Have a Crystal Report and get the sum of a field like this:

```
Sum({TheField})
```

and I put it in PageFooter section to have it in all pages but if the report has multiple pages it shows the sum of all fields and I need to get the sum per page.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get page level totals as follows. Create three formula fields in report design, namely `ff_Reset_Total`, `ff_Current_Total`, `ff_Add_Record` and set their values in formula editor as under:

1. ff_Reset_Total

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar PageTotl;
   PageTotl:=0;
   ```
2. ff_Current_Total

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar PageTotl;
   PageTotl;
   ```
3. ff_Add_Record

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar PageTotl;
   PageTotl:=PageTotl + {TheField};
   ```

Now place these formula fields in your report as under:

1. `ff_Reset_Total` in *Page Header* Section
2. `ff_Current_Total` in *Page Footer* Section
3. `ff_Add_Record` in your *Details* Section

Now hide `ff_Reset_Total` and `ff_Add_Record` by `Right Click` on each of them in *Page Header* and *Details* Sections, point to `Format Field` and then in the `Common` tab select `Suppress`

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in the report header.

```
numbervar runningtot;
runningtot:=0;
```

Add {TheField} to the variable on line level.

```
numbervar runningtot;
runningtot:=runningtot+{TheField};
```

Display the variable in the page footer A

```
numbervar runningtot;
runningtot;
```

Reset the variable to zero in page footer B

```
numbervar runningtot;
runningtot:=0;
```

You could display and reset the variable in one formula in page footer A, but the above is easier to digest..

Comment: Thanks but how should I create variable in report sections?

Comment: I strongly suggest you do some background reading on crystal reports, you can define and use variables in formulas. Formulas can be inserted into sections and they are executed as the section is printed, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: What do you mean by "line level"?