# get a sum per field on a page in crystal report [2]

Tags: crystal-reports

I have pretty much the same question as in [Get sum of a field per page in crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507655/get-sum-of-a-field-per-page-in-crystal-report) . The formmulas from that question work fine, but not perfectly, there is one little problem.
For example, on a first page there are 3 fields: 0, 0 and 1. So their sum is 1. On a next page, these fields are 0, 0, 0. Their sum should be obviously 0, but it stays as "1" still. How do i fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried o take out the "whileprintingrecords" from the formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A found a quite simple solution - just to move ff_Reset_Total in Footer section.